# Mapreduce Hbase file not found exception

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to populate data to Hbase using mapreduce but time and again its throwing the following exception :-

```
15/04/29 21:35:37 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/04/29 21:35:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/home/hduser/hadoopDir/mapred/staging/hduser2144453758/.staging/job_local2144453758_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
```

The jar which is given is in the path and provided to all nodes. Still it keeps on giving the error. Any help is appreciated.

Command is :-

```
    $ hadoop jar HBase-BulkImport.jar org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.Driver /user/466708/workexample/ output/ NBAFinal2010
```

logs:-

```
 15/04/29 21:35:37 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/04/29 21:35:38 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/home/hduser/hadoopDir/mapred/staging/hduser2144453758/.staging/job_local2144453758_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
```

Comment: What does `hdfs dfs -ls /usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib` results?

Comment: it yields the following result
ls: `/usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib': No such file or directory.              But what confuse me is why do we need to have the following jar in a folder in HDFS . When we have the jars in hadoop lib .

Answer (score 1):

Upload your `hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar` from local filesystem to hdfs locations as follows:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib
hdfs dfs -put /usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar /usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar
```

Now, try to run your job.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't helped though. Getting the same error. Would like to add already I have added the above given jar to hadoop classpath hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar      . How is adding jars to hdfs file system going to help.

Comment: Your job is looking for hbase lib files in hdfs folder and not in local filesystem. Thats why i have asked you to copy it to hdfs. Do you still get the same error: `File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar`?

Comment: yup getting the same error. How can I direct my job to look for the lib files in local file system ?

Comment: Have added the command and logs . Please check the edited question

Comment: Post the result for `hadoop fs -ls /usr/lib/hbase-0.98.12-hadoop2/lib`. There might be permission issue. Also try copying the hbase jars to hadoop lib folder.

Comment: the above command yields the output as                                                    hbase-protocol-0.98.12-‌​hadoop2.jar. Have also copied all the jars but the result remains the same. While compiling it prints the path which it takes and in it the above jar is present. My confusion is why it is searching the jar in HDFS file system.???

Comment: it worked out finally , I have to add all the dependent jar to the hdfs file system so as to make it work.

Comment: Works for me as well, I suggest the OP to accept this answer to benefit more people, I just upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens often when you have set the property `fs.defaultFS=hdfs://<cluster>` in core-site.xml or in some xml configuration of your hbase/hadoop environment.

If that's your case, the job submitter will always try to copy jar dependencies **from the defaultFS** (hdfs), and fail to find it.

I think in most configurations you don't actually need a fs.defaultFS pointing to hdfs, but a dfs.nameservices and an adecuate HA configuration in hdfs-site.xml.

Comment: are we sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact problem. You have to add the hbase library path to the **.bashrc** file. Add the lib folder in hbase to the CLASSPATH. 
Also, add the classpath of hbase to HADOOP_CLASSPATH.

Your **.bashrc** file should contain the following:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase mapredcp`

export CLASSPATH=${HBASE_HOME}/lib/*
```

Note: The CLASSPATH should point to the lib folder of your hbase installation folder. Use the following to compile and run your java code.

```
javac Example.java
java -classpath $CLASSPATH:. Example
```