# Why do I need hadoop lib jars into HDFS?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I created a MapReduce job and I'm testing in a multi-cluster environment, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://bigcluster:9000/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1293)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1314)
    at com.company.hbase.mapreduce.message.maestro.threadIndex.fakecolum.MockTestThreadIndexData.run(MockTestThreadIndexData.java:47)
    at com.company.hbase.mapreduce.MaestroUpdateJob.main(MaestroUpdateJob.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I see that `hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar` jar is missing on `hdfs://bigcluster:9000/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common`

The jar file exists on /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common, but my job is looking for inside HDFS.
If I copy all the jars (there are a lot of them) to HDFS, it worked. But the problem is, I want to understand, is it really necessary? Someone can explain to me WHY?
If I want to run it in production, do I need to make this? Is that correct?

Also, I see the answer [Why do I need to keep hbase/lib folder in hdfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877600/why-do-i-need-to-keep-hbase-lib-folder-in-hdfs/29121662#29121662) and yes, if I change the MapReduce framework to YARN, it works also. But I don't want to work with YARN and I just want to understand why I have to move all Hadoop libs to HDFS to run a MapReduce job.

## Updated

Here is how I instantiate the jobconf

```java
    Job job = Job.getInstance(config, "MyJob");
    
    Scan scan = createScan();
    Filter filter = createMyFilter();

    FilterList filters = createMyFilter();
    scan.setFilter(filters);
    
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
        MY_TABLE,
        scan,
        MyMapper.class,
        null,
        null,
        job
    );
    
    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(
        MY_TABLE,
        null,
        job
    );
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
```

Here is my `mapred-site.xml`

```xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
        <value>myhost:9001</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.ssl.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.ssl.require.client.cert</name>
        <value>false</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.ssl.hostname.verifier</name>
        <value>DEFAULT</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.ssl.keystores.factory.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.security.ssl.FileBasedKeyStoresFactory</value>
    <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.ssl.server.conf</name>
        <value>ssl-server.xml</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.ssl.client.conf</name>
        <value>ssl-client.xml</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

How I run this:

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`/opt/hbase/bin/hbase classpath` /opt/hadoop/bin/hadoop jar /tmp/mymapred-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

## Solution

Finally, I got the answer from this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31950822/13305602

Inside core-site.xml, there are two properties to configure the default File System inside Hadoop.

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://myhost.mycompany.com:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://myhost.mycompany.com:9000</value>
</property>
```

The default value of these two properties is `file://` see here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml

You can change this property on `core-site.xml` or if you are in an environment where you don't have access to that, you can do it only in job context setting on jobConf.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "file:///");
configuration.set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration, "MyJob");
```

Comment: You don't need that to run a MR job. Instead of looking for libraries locally it is searching them in HDFS. Could be due to an incorrect configuration, can you post your `mapred-site.xml` and the configurations set in the job. Also the command used to run the jar.

Comment: Do you have `HADOOP_HOME` set in your environment?

Comment: @mazaneicha No, I don't have. But I set this and the issue persists. If that's the issue, how set this properly?